# Google Spreadsheet - convert rows to text files

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a script/macro that I would like to convert the each rows in to a text file? I mean each row exported to separate text files. Then the exported text files will be saved into a google drive.  Here's my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1atSKR_scwi93TkFMKmFcQ6A7utZqkxgn0zscl_WdzPM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your spreadsheet is private. Other people can't look at it. Could you give an example of what those rows look like and what the text files should look like?

Comment: Do you really mean text files or google docs documents?

Comment: Can you try it again?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1atSKR_scwi93TkFMKmFcQ6A7utZqkxgn0zscl_WdzPM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Text files (.txt) and be saved in google drive

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is a script that saves all rows into text files. It saves them in a folder named "folderName". You need to replace that with the name of a real folder.

```
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("folderName").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    folder.createFile("row" + index + ".txt", row.join(", "));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Just a quick question, if is it possible to overwrite the previously created files in case I extract again?

Comment: You can move all files contained in the folder to the trash before writing the new files. I added that to my example.

Comment: I'm sorry..which part of the script is trashing?

Comment: `while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);`

Comment: so you mean manually remove files before re running the script?

Comment: when I tried to re run the script, it didn't overwrite the old files..it added the new ones

Comment: Did you use my new edited script? It should remove all the old files automatically.

Comment: I'm getting this error..Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

Comment: it's working now thanks...1 more :), what if I want to start the execution from row 2 (A2 and B2)?

Comment: You can change this line `var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());` to `var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());` to start in row 2. Or `var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn());` to start in row 3, etc.

Comment: Also, is it possible that the text files can be named with the name in first row?

Comment: I manage to make it work.  Can you let me know if it's the right approach?
function saveToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("TestFolder").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
     folder.createFile(sheet.getRange(index +1,1).getValue() + ".txt", row.join(", "));
  });
}

Comment: Looks good. However you could shorten it by replacing `sheet.getRange(index +1,1).getValue() ` with `row[0]`

Comment: Thanks SpiderPig19.  You've been very helpful.

Comment: btw, what if i want it to be saved to another google account's folder? is that possible?

Comment: Yes. But then you have to use the folder's id instead of it's name and the folder has to be shared of course. e.g. `var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");` To find the id just click on the folder and copy the last part of the URL.

Comment: I'm getting this message:
Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 6, file "")Dismiss

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzFuQ6-2ZuVHSThkejhtM1pTeDA&usp=sharing_eid&ts=561c6155

Comment: You need to change the line `var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("folderName").next();` to `var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID");`